# Android Mono version or Support package version

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Let's say I want to make sure all Android 7.0 devices can run my app.

When installing NuGet packages which version should I pay attention to?

Android Mono Version or the version of the Support package?

Should I choose A or B? By the way, is Android 7.0 the same thing as Android Mono 7.0 or are they not?

[image: A or B?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost MonoAndroid V7.0 and Android V7.0 are not the same things.

Mono Android is an open source implementation of Microsoft’s .NET Framework based on the open standards for the C# language and the Common Language Runtime, whereas Android is a mobile operating system developed by Google, based on a modified version of the Linux kernel and other open source software.

To Answer your First Question Support libraries actually work in a different way then you understand to make sure that your app works on all Android 7.0 devices you need to make sure you have the Android SDK and that your compilesdkversion is minimum this or greater than this, Now support libraries, on the other hand, are for compatibility suppose you have an app that targets V 5.1 and there is an API that is available on 5.1 but if you want to be able to use the same in your device below that you need to have support library V21 for more understanding read till the end.

Well trying to keep it as plain and simple as possible when you say the MonoAndroid version it basically shows you the version that you are targeting your android application on. Which basically means your targetted version which has nothing to do with the maximum support.

**Target Framework:**

> Target Framework – Specifies which framework to use in building your application. This API level is used at compile time by Xamarin.Android.

The Framework you want to target for your android application, And this actually is `A` as per you and this has nothing to do with whether or not it will run on a device higher than that it basically provides you with new features that are available to that Android framework.The Target Framework (also known as compileSdkVersion) is the specific Android framework version (API level) that your app is compiled for at build time. This setting specifies what APIs your app expects to use when it runs, but it has no effect on which APIs are actually available to your app when it is installed. As a result, changing the Target Framework setting does not change runtime behaviour.

For eg: If you target anything below V6.0 you don't need to provide any runtime permissions or if you target v8.0 you can use Adaptive icons and so on and so forth. The Target Framework identifies which library versions your application is linked against – this determines which APIs you can use in your app. For example, if you want to use the NotificationBuilder.SetCategory method that was introduced in Android 5.0 Lollipop, you must set the Target Framework to API Level 21 (Lollipop) or later. If you set your project's Target Framework to an API level such as API Level 19 (KitKat) and try to call the SetCategory method in your code, you will get a compile error.

Also Note:

> Beginning in August 2018, the Google Play Console will require that new apps target API level 26 (Android 8.0) or higher. Existing apps will be required to target API level 26 or higher beginning in November 2018. For more information, see Improving app security and performance on Google Play for years to come.

**Minimum Android Version**

> Minimum Android Version – Specifies the oldest Android version that you want your app to support. This API level is used at runtime by Android.

The Minimum Android version (also known as minSdkVersion) is the oldest version of the Android OS (i.e., the lowest API level) that can install and run your application. By default, an app can only be installed on devices matching the Target Framework setting or higher; if the Minimum Android version setting is lower than the Target Framework setting, your app can also run on earlier versions of Android. For example, if you set the Target Framework to Android 7.1 (Nougat) and set the Minimum Android version to Android 4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich), your app can be installed on any platform from API level 15 to API level 25, inclusive.

For eg: Although your app may successfully build and install on this range of platforms, this does not guarantee that it will successfully run on all of these platforms. For example, if your app is installed on Android 5.0 (Lollipop) and your code calls an API that is available only in Android 7.1 (Nougat) and newer, your app will get a runtime error and possibly crash. Therefore, your code must ensure – at runtime – that it calls only those APIs that are supported by the Android device that it is running on. In other words, your code must include explicit runtime checks to ensure that your app uses newer APIs only on devices that are recent enough to support them.

**Target Android Version**

> Target Android Version – Specifies the version of Android that your app is intended to run on. This API level is used at runtime by Android.

The Target Android Version (also known as targetSdkVersion) is the API level of the Android device where the app expects to run. Android uses this setting to determine whether to enable any compatibility behaviours – this ensures that your app continues to work the way you expect. Android uses the Target Android version setting of your app to figure out which behaviour changes can be applied to your app without breaking it (this is how Android provides forward compatibility).

The Target Framework and the Target Android version, while having very similar names, are not the same thing. The Target Framework setting communicates target API level information to Xamarin.Android for use at compile time, while the Target Android version communicates target API level information to Android for use at runtime (when the app is installed and running on a device).

In general, the Target Android Version should be bounded by the Minimum Android Version and the Target Framework. That is:

**Minimum Android Version <= Target Android Version <= Target Framework**

**Support Libraries**

Android Support Libraries are an essential part of every Android application and you’ll find them absolutely everywhere. The Support Libraries offer developers the ability to add the latest and greatest features of Android to their application while maintaining backwards compatibility with older versions of Android. As new versions of the Android SDK continue to roll out, so do updates to the Support Libraries; keeping them up-to-date and installing the correct versions is an important (and sometimes frustrating) part of Android development. In this blog, I hope to demystify the Support Libraries and help you upgrade to the latest versions

For more understanding and Reference for Support libraries:https://blog.xamarin.com/mastering-android-support-libraries/